# android imageview takes extra black space

Tags: android, imageview

the imageview takes extra [black] space and i dont know why

ok this imageview should wrap content but instead..

[photo explains the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ORiF.png)

this is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/map" /><ImageView
android:id="@+id/blxx"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:paddingBottom="-20dp"
android:src="@drawable/photo" />



<ImageView
android:id="@+id/blxx"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/blxx" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? you have 3 images views which one is the one with the problem? You also have 2 images views with the same id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first possible reason for your problem:

sometimes when the image is too small, it can't scratch anymore then some limit. after that limit - what happens is what you see - blank space claimed by the imageView where additional scratch of the image was expected.    I advice you to take larger picture (with bigger resolution)

Second possible reason:

add to your imageView properties on the xml file the following attribute:

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Answer (score 10):

Try the below:

```
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
```

This will remove the extra padded space

Comment: this worked well as `android:scaleType="fitXY"` was stretching my image

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Above line is centering the image to fit inside your ImageView. Try without it. If not, set gravity to "fill" and try again.

Also remove one of the duplicates of blxx as noted.

Answer (score 0):

hope this ll help you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_gravity="center">


<ImageView
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_content"
android:src="@drawable/map" /> 

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```